# How to clone a user in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms, permissions

Is there a way to clone users' security and permissions in Microsoft SQL Server, preferably using the SQL Server Management Studio GUI?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**Note :** *The below script doesn't actually set the permissions on anything, it just creates the script that can be copied and pasted to a new query, which can then be edited before being executed.*

Below script will help you copy/clone permissions of one user to another:

```
--- To copy permissions of one user/role to another user/role.

USE database_name -- Use the database from which you want to extract the permissions
GO


SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @OldUser sysname, @NewUser sysname

SET @OldUser = 'userOLD' --The user or role from which to copy the permissions from
SET @NewUser = 'userNEW'  --The user or role to which to copy the permissions to


SELECT  'USE' + SPACE(1) + QUOTENAME(DB_NAME()) AS '--Database Context'


SELECT  '--Cloning permissions from' + SPACE(1) + QUOTENAME(@OldUser) + SPACE(1) + 'to' + SPACE(1) + QUOTENAME(@NewUser) AS '--Comment'


SELECT  'EXEC sp_addrolemember @rolename ='
    + SPACE(1) + QUOTENAME(USER_NAME(rm.role_principal_id), '''') + ', @membername =' + SPACE(1) + QUOTENAME(@NewUser, '''') AS '--Role Memberships'
FROM    sys.database_role_members AS rm
WHERE   USER_NAME(rm.member_principal_id) = @OldUser
ORDER BY rm.role_principal_id ASC


SELECT  CASE WHEN perm.state <> 'W' THEN perm.state_desc ELSE 'GRANT' END
    + SPACE(1) + perm.permission_name + SPACE(1) + 'ON ' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(obj.schema_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(obj.name)
    + CASE WHEN cl.column_id IS NULL THEN SPACE(0) ELSE '(' + QUOTENAME(cl.name) + ')' END
    + SPACE(1) + 'TO' + SPACE(1) + QUOTENAME(@NewUser) COLLATE database_default
    + CASE WHEN perm.state <> 'W' THEN SPACE(0) ELSE SPACE(1) + 'WITH GRANT OPTION' END AS '--Object Level Permissions'
FROM    sys.database_permissions AS perm
    INNER JOIN
    sys.objects AS obj
    ON perm.major_id = obj.[object_id]
    INNER JOIN
    sys.database_principals AS usr
    ON perm.grantee_principal_id = usr.principal_id
    LEFT JOIN
    sys.columns AS cl
    ON cl.column_id = perm.minor_id AND cl.[object_id] = perm.major_id
WHERE   usr.name = @OldUser
ORDER BY perm.permission_name ASC, perm.state_desc ASC


SELECT  CASE WHEN perm.state <> 'W' THEN perm.state_desc ELSE 'GRANT' END
    + SPACE(1) + perm.permission_name + SPACE(1)
    + SPACE(1) + 'TO' + SPACE(1) + QUOTENAME(@NewUser) COLLATE database_default
    + CASE WHEN perm.state <> 'W' THEN SPACE(0) ELSE SPACE(1) + 'WITH GRANT OPTION' END AS '--Database Level Permissions'
FROM    sys.database_permissions AS perm
    INNER JOIN
    sys.database_principals AS usr
    ON perm.grantee_principal_id = usr.principal_id
WHERE   usr.name = @OldUser
AND perm.major_id = 0
ORDER BY perm.permission_name ASC, perm.state_desc ASC
```

Comment: Thanks for the super reply Kin, but it would be great if it has GUI steps. I am not good at codes as I am totally new to SQL.

Comment: @sweetritz If there was a GUI for cloning a user, you wouldn't need to ask the question, because you could just press the button. There isn't. Just because you're "not good at codes" is no excuse to not learn to be better...

Comment: Dont get yourself limited to just using GUI. GUI is good for novice, but it is limited. For your task, above script will just generate **actual scripts that you can use to create/clone user**.

Comment: thanks Aaron for the advise :) and @Kin thanks for the help, that was really quick reply, much appreciated :):)

Comment: I think it needs to be clear that running the above script doesn't actually set the permissions on anything, it just creates the script that can be copied and pasted to a new query, which can then be edited before being executed. I just used it myself and it worked perfectly! Great time saver!!

Comment: @AlanFisher thanks for your comment and glad that it helped you. Updated my answer to reflect your comment. Thanks !

Comment: This is genius!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a very nice script by Pavel Pawlowski to do the job:
http://www.pawlowski.cz/2011/03/cloning-user-rights-database/

Main advantage:

- script/copy **Role Memberships**
- script/copy **Object Level Permissions**
- script/copy **Database Level Permissions**

**I'm NOT the author of this script.** The script is copy-pasted from [this link](http://www.pawlowski.cz/2011/03/cloning-user-rights-database/) on Pavel Pawlowski blog, see the link for more information on how to use the script.

```
USE [master]
GO
--============================================
-- Author:      Pavel Pawlowski
-- Created:     2010/04/16
-- Description: Copies rights of old user to new user
--==================================================
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_CloneRights (
    @oldUser sysname, --Old user from which to copy right
    @newUser sysname, --New user to which copy rights
    @printOnly bit = 1, --When 1 then only script is printed on screen, when 0 then also script is executed, when NULL, script is only executed and not printed
    @NewLoginName sysname = NULL --When a NewLogin name is provided also a creation of user is part of the final script
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    CREATE TABLE #output (
        command nvarchar(4000)
    )

    DECLARE
        @command nvarchar(4000),
        @sql nvarchar(max),
        @dbName nvarchar(128),
        @msg nvarchar(max)

    SELECT
        @sql = N'',
        @dbName = QUOTENAME(DB_NAME())

    IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.database_principals where name = @oldUser))
    BEGIN
        SET @msg = 'Source user ' + QUOTENAME(@oldUser) + ' doesn''t exists in database ' + @dbName
        RAISERROR(@msg, 11,1)
        RETURN
    END   

    INSERT INTO #output(command)
    SELECT '--Database Context' AS command UNION ALL
    SELECT    'USE' + SPACE(1) + @dbName UNION ALL
    SELECT 'SET XACT_ABORT ON'

    IF (ISNULL(@NewLoginName, '') <> '')
    BEGIN       
        SET @sql = N'USE ' + @dbName + N';
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = @newUser)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #output(command)
            SELECT ''--Create user'' AS command

            INSERT INTO #output(command)
            SELECT 
                ''CREATE USER '' + QUOTENAME(@NewUser) + '' FOR LOGIN '' + QUOTENAME(@NewLoginName) +
                    CASE WHEN ISNULL(default_schema_name, '''') <> '''' THEN '' WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = '' + QUOTENAME(dp.default_schema_name)
                        ELSE ''''
                    END AS Command
            FROM sys.database_principals dp
            INNER JOIN sys.server_principals sp ON dp.sid = sp.sid
            WHERE dp.name = @OldUser
        END'

        EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@OldUser sysname, @NewUser sysname, @NewLoginName sysname', @OldUser = @OldUser, @NewUser = @NewUser, @NewLoginName=@NewLoginName
    END

    INSERT INTO #output(command)
    SELECT    '--Cloning permissions from' + SPACE(1) + QUOTENAME(@OldUser) + SPACE(1) + 'to' + SPACE(1) + QUOTENAME(@NewUser)


    INSERT INTO #output(command)
    SELECT '--Role Memberships' AS command

    SET @sql = N'USE ' + @dbName + N';
    INSERT INTO #output(command)
    SELECT ''EXEC sp_addrolemember @rolename ='' 
        + SPACE(1) + QUOTENAME(USER_NAME(rm.role_principal_id), '''''''') + '', @membername ='' + SPACE(1) + QUOTENAME(@NewUser, '''''''') AS command
    FROM    sys.database_role_members AS rm
    WHERE    USER_NAME(rm.member_principal_id) = @OldUser
    ORDER BY rm.role_principal_id ASC'

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@OldUser sysname, @NewUser sysname', @OldUser = @OldUser, @NewUser = @NewUser


    INSERT INTO #output(command)
    SELECT '--Object Level Permissions'

    SET @sql = N'USE ' + @dbName + N';
    INSERT INTO #output(command)
    SELECT    CASE WHEN perm.state <> ''W'' THEN perm.state_desc ELSE ''GRANT'' END
        + SPACE(1) + perm.permission_name + SPACE(1) + ''ON '' + QUOTENAME(USER_NAME(obj.schema_id)) + ''.'' + QUOTENAME(obj.name) 
        + CASE WHEN cl.column_id IS NULL THEN SPACE(0) ELSE ''('' + QUOTENAME(cl.name) + '')'' END
        + SPACE(1) + ''TO'' + SPACE(1) + QUOTENAME(@NewUser) COLLATE database_default
        + CASE WHEN perm.state <> ''W'' THEN SPACE(0) ELSE SPACE(1) + ''WITH GRANT OPTION'' END
    FROM    sys.database_permissions AS perm
        INNER JOIN
        sys.objects AS obj
        ON perm.major_id = obj.[object_id]
        INNER JOIN
        sys.database_principals AS usr
        ON perm.grantee_principal_id = usr.principal_id
        LEFT JOIN
        sys.columns AS cl
        ON cl.column_id = perm.minor_id AND cl.[object_id] = perm.major_id
    WHERE    usr.name = @OldUser
    ORDER BY perm.permission_name ASC, perm.state_desc ASC'

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@OldUser sysname, @NewUser sysname', @OldUser = @OldUser, @NewUser = @NewUser


    INSERT INTO #output(command)
    SELECT N'--Database Level Permissions'

    SET @sql = N'USE ' + @dbName + N';
    INSERT INTO #output(command)
    SELECT    CASE WHEN perm.state <> ''W'' THEN perm.state_desc ELSE ''GRANT'' END
        + SPACE(1) + perm.permission_name + SPACE(1)
        + SPACE(1) + ''TO'' + SPACE(1) + QUOTENAME(@NewUser) COLLATE database_default
        + CASE WHEN perm.state <> ''W'' THEN SPACE(0) ELSE SPACE(1) + ''WITH GRANT OPTION'' END
    FROM    sys.database_permissions AS perm
        INNER JOIN
        sys.database_principals AS usr
        ON perm.grantee_principal_id = usr.principal_id
    WHERE    usr.name = @OldUser
    AND    perm.major_id = 0
    ORDER BY perm.permission_name ASC, perm.state_desc ASC'

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@OldUser sysname, @NewUser sysname', @OldUser = @OldUser, @NewUser = @NewUser

    DECLARE cr CURSOR FOR
        SELECT command FROM #output

    OPEN cr

    FETCH NEXT FROM cr INTO @command

    SET @sql = ''

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        IF (@printOnly IS NOT NULL)
            PRINT @command

        SET @sql = @sql + @command + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
        FETCH NEXT FROM cr INTO @command
    END

    CLOSE cr
    DEALLOCATE cr

    IF (@printOnly IS NULL OR @printOnly = 0)
        EXEC (@sql)

    DROP TABLE #output
END
GO
EXECUTE sp_ms_marksystemobject 'dbo.sp_CloneRights'
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on @Kin-shah's awesome answer, I wrote a script, that can copy permissions **of all databases** in one sql server instance. It is much worse readable, but might come in handy, if you have many users and many databases:

```
USE master
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES r WHERE r.ROUTINE_NAME = 'clone_user')
DROP PROCEDURE clone_user
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE clone_user @database sysname, @OldUser sysname, @NewUser sysname AS BEGIN

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
SET @sql = '

USE '+@database+'

DECLARE @database sysname = '''+@database+'''
DECLARE @OldUser sysname = '''+@OldUser+'''
DECLARE @NewUser sysname = '''+@NewUser+'''

SET NOCOUNT ON

SELECT  ''EXEC sp_addrolemember @rolename =''
    + SPACE(1) + QUOTENAME(USER_NAME(rm.role_principal_id), '''''''') + '', @membername ='' + SPACE(1) + QUOTENAME(@NewUser, '''''''') AS ''--Role Memberships''
INTO #roles
FROM    sys.database_role_members AS rm
WHERE   USER_NAME(rm.member_principal_id) = @OldUser
ORDER BY rm.role_principal_id ASC

SELECT  CASE WHEN perm.state <> ''W'' THEN perm.state_desc ELSE ''GRANT'' END
    + SPACE(1) + perm.permission_name + SPACE(1) + ''ON '' + QUOTENAME(USER_NAME(obj.schema_id)) + ''.'' + QUOTENAME(obj.name)
    + CASE WHEN cl.column_id IS NULL THEN SPACE(0) ELSE ''('' + QUOTENAME(cl.name) + '')'' END
    + SPACE(1) + ''TO'' + SPACE(1) + QUOTENAME(@NewUser) COLLATE database_default
    + CASE WHEN perm.state <> ''W'' THEN SPACE(0) ELSE SPACE(1) + ''WITH GRANT OPTION'' END AS ''--Object Level Permissions''
INTO #grant1
FROM    sys.database_permissions AS perm
    INNER JOIN
    sys.objects AS obj
    ON perm.major_id = obj.[object_id]
    INNER JOIN
    sys.database_principals AS usr
    ON perm.grantee_principal_id = usr.principal_id
    LEFT JOIN
    sys.columns AS cl
    ON cl.column_id = perm.minor_id AND cl.[object_id] = perm.major_id
WHERE   usr.name = @OldUser
ORDER BY perm.permission_name ASC, perm.state_desc ASC

SELECT  CASE WHEN perm.state <> ''W'' THEN perm.state_desc ELSE ''GRANT'' END
    + SPACE(1) + perm.permission_name + SPACE(1)
    + SPACE(1) + ''TO'' + SPACE(1) + QUOTENAME(@NewUser) COLLATE database_default
    + CASE WHEN perm.state <> ''W'' THEN SPACE(0) ELSE SPACE(1) + ''WITH GRANT OPTION'' END AS ''--Database Level Permissions''
INTO #grant2
FROM    sys.database_permissions AS perm
    INNER JOIN
    sys.database_principals AS usr
    ON perm.grantee_principal_id = usr.principal_id
WHERE   usr.name = @OldUser
AND perm.major_id = 0
ORDER BY perm.permission_name ASC, perm.state_desc ASC


IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #roles UNION ALL SELECT * FROM #grant1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM #grant2) BEGIN
SELECT  ''USE ''+@database AS ''-- '+@database+'/'+@OldUser+''' INTO #tmp
SELECT * FROM #tmp UNION ALL SELECT * FROM #roles UNION ALL SELECT * FROM #grant1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM #grant2
END

'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql

END

GO

EXEC sp_MSforeachdb 'EXECUTE [dbo].[clone_user] ?, ''OldUser'', ''NewUser'''

DROP PROCEDURE clone_user
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click database in Object Explorer
2. Tasks-> Generate Scripts...
3. Select Only Users section and finish the wizard as is

[image]

Note:finally you get the script for all user creation and their roles almost ready. 
but this will not create script for Granting **Execute** permission for Stored Procedures even if you Select **Script Object-Level Permissions** to true.

[image]

Comment: It wont work: it will not generate script to grant execution on stored procedures

Comment: Yes you are right. I have added some clarification